# How show multicursor only from cursor position?

Tags: multiple-cursors

emacs 26

in my *scratch* buffer I select dash

[image]

Now I want to show multicursors only from cursor position (line 5).

```
M-x mc/mark-all-like-this
```

But it show multicursors in whole buffer

[image]

I also try `M-x mc/mark-next-like-this`
[image]

But it not help.
[image]

But I need to show multicursors only from cursor position (line 5).

Comment: The simplest solution in these cases is to narrow your buffer so you can safely edit a known chunk of your buffer.

Comment: Could you please rephrase? From where to where do you want multiple cursors?   "show multicursors only from cursor position (line 5)" does not make much sense in conjunction with multiple-cursors.

Comment: @jue multicursors must be only from "aa-bb" to "cc-dd" (only 4 rows)

Comment: Then its simple. Do `M-x mc/mark-next-like-this` 3 times and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

multiple-cursors provides the functions `mc/mark-next-like-this` and `mc/mark-previous-like-this` for this. See the [manual](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) for more details.

Comment: It's not help. I updated my post

Comment: If you look at the multiple cursors manual and demos, the usual way to do this is bind mc/mark-next-like-this to `C->`. Then you can press `C->` three times to mark the four spots you want.

Comment: but if I has 100 lines. I need to press C-> 100 times. I think it's not good.

Comment: If you want to mark all the hyphens to the end of the buffer, just hold the key down until it stops adding more - it will give you the message "no more matches found"

Comment: @Alexei did you know, that you can do stuff multiple times by pressing `Control` and the number keys before pressing the shortcut you want? For example `C-3 C->` to mark all 4 lines at once. Maybe it is a good idea to read the manuals.